# Mac application with snow leopard canot run in leopard os

Tags: macos, xcode4.2, osx-snow-leopard, osx-leopard

I am working in a mac application with snowleopard.This application is created with leopard os,but this not support in lion due to some external application.So we converted this to snow leopard and work fine .Now the client need to convert this application to leopard version ,for that i am using the xcode 4.2 and lion os and convert the bsec SDK to Mac osx 10.5 and  Architecture to 32_bit intel ,but we getting an error `"The run destination My Mac 64-bit is not valid for Running the scheme 'AppName'."`
 How can avoid this error ?

I want to test this application with 10.5 os, but we have only the 10.6 & 10.7 osx,
1)where we get the leopard osx ?
2)Has the Apple issue leopard osx now?
3)Is any problem for instal the leopard os to new MAC system(iMac,Macmini,Macbook)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem a while back, but I'm recalling the solution from memory, as my company dropped 10.5 support meanwhile. The details might be a little bit off, but it should get you going in the right direction:

1. Grab the latest version of Xcode 3 from the Apple Website
2. Install it on a Mac. (Make sure you removed the Developer directory if this Mac had another  version of Xcode already installed).
3. Under /Developer, locate the 10.5.sdk directory. Move this directory to a save place (outside of /Developer).
4. Install Xcode 4.2.
5. Look where Xcode 4.2 installed its sdk's. Put your previously saved 10.5.sdk directory next to it.
6. Restart Xcode. There should be 10.5 SDK option in the SDK drop down menu now.